# Protractor if else with expect(condition)

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor, cucumber

In my script, I need to include if-else condition to verify whether the expected=actual.If they are not matching it should go to the else block and print "StepFailed".But, always its executing the if block and the o/p is "step passed"  although expected≠Actual.Below is my code:

```
var expected = ['Select training program using Index', 'Selenium','A','UFT/QTP','Loadrunner'];
var els = element.all(by.xpath("//select[@id='dropdown1']/option"));
   for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; ++i) {
     if(expect(els.get(i).getText()).to.eventually.equals(expected[i])){
        console.log('' +'Steppassed'+ '');
     }else{
        console.log('' +'Stepfailed'+ '');
     }
});
```

Drop down values are:'Select training program using Index', 'Selenium', 
      'Appium','UFT/QTP','Loadrunner'.If you would have observed I have given 'A' instead of "Appium' and hence the step should fail but that's not happening.

kindly suggest me how this can be resolved.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing there is no need of asserting if you are checking a conditional value

you could do something like this -

```
var expected = ['Select training program using Index', 'Selenium', 
'A','UFT/QTP','Loadrunner'];

var els = element.all(by.xpath("//select[@id='dropdown1']/option"));

for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; ++i) {
   els.get(i).getText().then((text) => {
       if(text === expected[i] ) {
           console.log('' +'Steppassed'+ '');
         } else {
            console.log('' +'Stepfailed'+ '');
           }
         });
       }
```

You can also use async/await syntax for better handling & readability of promises!

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Comment: Bro, Could you please me with my my inbuilt reporter and hooks file.I need to update that as well. I am new to protractor with cucumber-typescript.

Comment: You could check this repo for guidance - https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript and ya if you face any issues you always open up a question here in SO

Comment: Hahaa Bro, I have been using your repo code from past 2 months.The thing I have observed is that the report is changing every time you run a script.I actually wanted 2 reports if I am running 2 times and morever, screenshots are not under each test step.Any update on this?

Comment: ok, can you create github issues in that repo so that I could add them as enhancements to the current framework?

Comment: Ram Pasala: Created a github issue.Hoping that it will be resolved soon.Thank you.